# How to perform an operation on every two columns of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Right now I have a `NumPy` array of `0`'s and `1`'s and I want to perform a `logical_and` on every *two* columns. A `for` loop achieving this would look as follows:

```
import numpy as np
result = []
data = [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]]
np_data = np.array(data)
num_cols = len(np_data[1,:])
for i in range(0, num_cols):
    for j in range(i+1, num_cols):
        #Comparing every column with every other column
        anded = np.logical_and(np_data[:,i], np_data[:,j])
        result.append(anded)
print result
```

I was just wondering whether there was a `NumPy`-fied way to do this since obviously `for` loops are not good for operating on `NumPy` arrays.

Comment: Is that really the form of 'result' you want? You will need some small code to figure out where i,j is located in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, notice that result is the transpose of your result (Also in this case result is a 2d array and in your case it is a list of 1darrays).

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> I, J = np.array(list(combinations([0,1,2], 2))).T
>>> result = np.logical_and(np_data[:, I], np_data[:, J])
>>> result
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> result.T
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I didn't know you could put a list as the index of a numpy array, very useful, and itertools is awesome too!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a smarter way to construct the index lists ii,jj but this does the same as your code for your example:

```
import numpy as np
data = [[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]]
np_data = np.array(data)
q=range(len(data))
ii,jj=zip(*[[i,j] for i in q for j in q if i<j])
result=np.transpose(np.logical_and(np_data[:,list(ii)],np_data[:,list(jj)]))
```

Edit: for `ii,jj` you can also use this (inspired by Bago):

```
ii,jj = np.array(list(combinations(q, 2))).T
```

Comment: Oh, yes, itertools combinations as Bago points out was what I was looking for but I did not have time to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have an array (n,m) with n rows and m columns, then you can get the logical and between all possible columns as an array (m,m) where each element is an array of size n.  This is similar to your result, but double the size (no triangular matrix).

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1]])
n,m = data.shape
dist0 = np.tile(data.T,(m,1)).reshape(m,m,n) # repeat columns along axis 0
dist1 = np.tile(data.T,(1,m)).reshape(m,m,n) # repeat columns along axis 1
result = np.logical_and(dist0, dist1)
# now result[i,j] contains the logical_and bewteen column i and j
print(result[0,2])
[False  True  True]
```